# Rails app works completely fine in production but not in development mode on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ever since I deployed my app and compiled all its assets, it has been completely buggy in development mode but completely fine on heroku.

The javascript does not fully work in development, and the ajax is very slow and buggy.

I'm hypothesizing that it's because whenever I run rails s, it always uses thin in development, and I'd like to force the use of webrick to see if thin is just buggy locally. How can I force the use of webrick instead of thin? I'm using thin in production, only. And if thin is not the reason locally, what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
rails s webrick
```

to force rails to use webrick.

(A lot of the command options work like this as well for instance to start with mongrel (assuming you've got the gem) it's `rails s mongrel`)

Comment: thanks, running in webrick solved some of the bugs in development mode on the local server, but not fully. This only happened after deploying to heroku. I've since updated the app and have pushed to heroku since the initial deployment and all works fine except locally on the local server in development mode. Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: are the rails versions on production and on the local environment the same? Ruby versions?

Comment: yes they are, i really don't understand. This never happened before I deployed it.

Comment: are the gems listed in the gemfile using explicit versions? Are the gems in the enviornments the same when you run `bundle`

Comment: Ae few of the gems I have are using explicit versions. The gems in the environments are the same.

Comment: Are there major differences in the config/database.yml between production and development? Or config/environments/*  ?

Comment: on Heroku, I'm using postgres. I did not touch the database.yml file. I instead specified to use the PG gem in production in my gem file.

Comment: and config/environments haven't been altered from the scaffolded versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I didn't scaffold anything.

Comment: Ok, one last question. What browser are you using? How are you accessing your local environment? http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost

Comment: ok, well i'm going to suggest testing it using 127.0.0.1:3000 if that doesn't clear up some of the bugs i'm sort of stumped.